# Changing toaster class from the controller toaster.pop()

Tags: css, angularjs

Im using toaster for angular:

```
https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster
```

This is my directive:

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000}"></toaster-container>
```

all good here, what i want to do is this, right now it shows me all the msgs in right top corner of the screen, which is what i want (it's also the default behavior), i want to do (for some particular msgs) this:

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'position-class': 'toast-top-full-width'}"></toaster-container>
```

Now i can't seem to find any option to change the position class from the pop() method:

```
https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster/pull/40/files?short_path=04c6e90
```

What i currently have is simple msgs like:

```
toaster.pop('success','Redirecting to paypal');
```

And i need something like this:

```
   toaster.pop('success','Redirecting to paypal',{'position-class':'toast-top-full-width'});
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually post the toaster configuration in my index page, since I'm using toaster to send notifications across the system that's a suitable place to write it and not repeat the configuration.

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{
  'closeButton': false,
  'debug': false,
  'positionClass': 'toast-top-right',
  'onclick': null,
  'showDuration': '200',
  'hideDuration': '1000',
  'timeOut': '5000',
  'extendedTimeOut': '1000',
  'showEasing': 'swing',
  'hideEasing': 'linear',
  'showMethod': 'fadeIn',
  'hideMethod': 'fadeOut'
}"></toaster-container>
```

don't forget to include the file
AngularJS-Toaster/toaster.css to your index reference

then the signature for the pop is the following:

```
(type, title, body, timeout, bodyOutputType, clickHandler)
```

so you'll have to do something like

```
toaster.pop('success','Redirecting to paypal',null,'5000','toast-top-full-width');
```